# Why is my Ruby program slowing x100 as I add 10,000 objects?

Tags: ruby, performance, memory-management

There's no i/o, no database, no puts statements. I have a central object that I instantiate, it has a couple of Set.new creations in its initialize method. (I changed the Set.new to Array.new to no effect).

I wanted to do a memory load test, but found that the performance of a single call to my system increased roughly linearly from 1 x 10-4 up to 160 x 10-4 as I called 20,000 times (adding a new object each call). So I never got to the memory testing part...

I narrowed the time increase to the Muffin.new statement, with the two Set.new creations inside the initialize.

It seems odd that memory allocation or object creation should take time proportional to the number of objects created, but that's what I think I'm seeing.

Am I missing something? Is this the case? Is there something else I should be looking at or considering.?

Comment: You must have some kind of geometric scaling problem, but you will need to post a minimal amount of code that demonstrates this phenomenon or it's impossible to say.

Comment: To withdraw the question, your intention, just click on delete.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the Garbage Collector is at work... Try using GC.disable before the allocation and GC.enable after to see if it corrects the issue.

I'm not a Ruby expert, but Ruby's Garbage Collection implementation may not be the best thing about this langage. Read [this](http://samsaffron.com/archive/2013/11/22/demystifying-the-ruby-gc) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies: found the place where I was doing a "collect" over all the items in the collection; so of course it is linear in the number of objects. Took that out and the time is constant, as it should be.

Needless to say, I withdraw the question.